# My Google Pie Chart is displaying no data even though query works . ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, google-visualization, reporting

I struggling with trying to figure out why my `Google Pie Chart` is failing to display the data even though my `query` works perfectly in the `Query builder` when I tested it.

I'm still pretty new to this and I have a basic understanding but I can't seem to spot the problem? If anyone can help me with a solution I'll greatly appreciate it. I'm currently developing in `ASP.NET MVC` and I'm running everything off my `view page` using `Razor` for this **report**. If anyone needs additional code, please let me know and thanks in advance.

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using WebMatrix.WebData;


@{
    var db = Database.Open("HealthContext");

    String rows = "";

    var Query = ("SELECT Hospital.Name,Hospital.Province,Count([Order].OrderID) AS Orders FROM Hospital,[Order] WHERE Hospital.HospitalID = [Order].HospitalID GROUP BY Hospital.Name,Hospital.Province;");

    var AppQuery = db.Query(Query);


    List<string> rowsList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in AppQuery)
    {
        rowsList.Add("['" + item.Name + "', '" + item.Province + "','" + item.Orders + "']");


    };

    rows = String.Join(", ", rowsList);

    }

<h2>PieChart1</h2>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');

        data.addColumn('string', 'Province');

        data.addColumn('number', 'Orders');
        @Html.Raw(rows);

        var options = {
            title: 'Orders Per Hospital'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just outputting your row data into your drawChart() function without actually specifying it as data for the DataTable.

Try:

```
data.addRows([
    @Html.Raw(rows)
]);
```

I haven't actually used Google's visualization API, but I'm going based on: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

Comment: Alright - this seemed to get rid of the no data. However, it doesn't display anything at all. Just the Title of the chart, so I went to the inspector and it gave me this error `Invalid type, undefined, for column "3"` and I proceeded to change this line `data.addColumn('number', 'Orders');` since it's row 3 (I'm assuming) to `string` but no good.

Comment: In your foreach loop, you are wrapping the `item.Orders` value in quotes, so it's treating it as a string. Can you try removing those quotes and then changing back to `data.addColumn('number', 'Orders');`?

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, just now getting back to this. The data format for Pie Chart is [label, value]. You have 3 columns and the Pie Chart does not know how to render it. If you change your rows to be something like ['Hospital Name (Province)', Orders] and then remove one of your string columns, it should work.

Comment: That seemed to work, but I completely removed province. However, it doesn't display correctly. Could you perhaps give me an example of how to change the row properly?

Comment: I asked another question pertaining to this new issue. Felt it would be better to ask a new question since this your suggestions to THIS question has fixed the issue of not displaying data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668433/google-pie-chart-not-displaying-correctly-on-view-page-in-asp-net-mvc